# unable to get proper data with AngularJS post method

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, codeigniter, http-post

this is my 1st time with AngulerJS. I'm trying to `POST` data to the server.

**AngularJS Code**

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
var BASE_URL = "http://localhost/project/api/Data/";

var GET_DATA = BASE_URL+"get_data";
console.log(GET_DATA);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
var inputs = { "user_id": "3"};
var config = {
              headers : {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
              }
          }
$http.post(GET_DATA , inputs, config)
          .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.content = response.error;
              $scope.statuscode = response.status;
              $scope.statustext = response.statusInfo;
              console.log(response);    
          })
          .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
              $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                  "<hr />status: " + status +
                  "<hr />headers: " + header +
                  "<hr />config: " + config;
          });

});
```

This code is posting data to the server, but with something wired format. Below is my `print_r($_POST);` result :

```
Array
(
    [{"user_id":"3"}] => 
    [0] => 
)
```

this is wrong result, I am expecting something like

```
Array
(
    user_id => 3
)
```

Note : I'm using CodeIgniter framework at server side.

Comment: `var inputs =  "user_id=3";`

Comment: @MayankVadiya what if I want to send multiple key:value ? and Files as well

Comment: than you can use `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send your post data in `json`:

```
$http.post(GET_DATA , {"user_id": "3"})
      .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.content = response.error;
          $scope.statuscode = response.status;
          $scope.statustext = response.statusInfo;
          console.log(response);    
       })
      .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
          $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
             "<hr />status: " + status +
             "<hr />headers: " + header +
             "<hr />config: " + config;
       });
});
```

And in the server side you can get the post data like this:

```
$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($postdata);
```

You have to encode your data in the post body in `urlencoded` format when the request content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Which should be like this:

```
var inputs = 'student_id=3';
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not the right practice to write answer of old question but I want to post this answer so that others can take help whenever they required.

Firstly, understand the reason why such thing is happening. The reason is, AngularJS doesn’t serialize the data ( parameters ) passed to the POST request automatically. Therefore we have to serialize the data with`$httpParamSerializerJQLike` which is available as AngularJS Service . Also the default content-type of the posted data is application/json. Therefore we need to override the Content-type headers of the post request to application/x-www-form-urlencoded in order to access the the posted values via $_POST.

Now in angular there is also provided `$httpParamSerializer` service but the difference `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` is something object also containing another object so if former is used, then internal object won't be serialized i.e. all nested objects won't be serialized with `$httpParamSerializer` but it is not the case with `$httpParamSerializerJQLike`.

You can check the difference here: [AngularJS $httpParamSerializer service DOC](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L28)

Now, rather than `json` encode and decode data in `php`, we can do that in Angular JS itself by using `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` service in angular JS in this way:

```
$http({
        url: myUrl,   //post your url here
        method: 'POST',
        data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({ 'user_id': '3'}),
       headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       }
      });
```

And in codeigniter you can get that posted data by normal syntax i.e. `$this->input->post('user_id');`

For more information...you can refer the above link mentioned...

Hope it might help you....