# angular $http post not working well

Tags: php, angularjs

i try send post with $http to php,its working well but when i want to test if $_post['action'] == 'getPayments' then this not reponse nothing.

This is my $http post:

```
 var req = {
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'process.php',
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'json'
         },
         data: 'action=getPayments'
        }

        $http(req).then(function(req){
            console.log(req.data);
            $scope.bidslist = req.data;
        }, function(){

        });
```

And this is php:

```
$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : (isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '');

if ( !empty($action) ) {

    switch ( $action ) {

              case 'getPayments':     

                  some code goes here
                  echo json_encode($myArray);

              break;
     }
}
```

I can see it in debug console that this send post with action=getPayments but in php side its not recogonize the post only when i remove switch its working..

I don't have any errors just no response from php what is the issue?

Comment: I was having same issue, please take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232651/unable-to-get-proper-data-with-angularjs-post-method

Comment: you need to pass the `data` to php script as a object ,`{data: '"action"="getPayments"}'`.

Comment: AP u helped me a lot thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Content-Type to be **application/json**

```
var req = {
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'process.php',
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
         data: 'action=getPayments'
        }

        $http(req).then(function(req){
            console.log(req.data);
            $scope.bidslist = req.data;
        }, function(){

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

data has to be a an object payload,

```
var data = {action: getPayments(what's this?)};
var req = {
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'process.php',
         data: data
        }

        $http(req).then(function(req){
            console.log(req.data);
            $scope.bidslist = req.data;
        }, function(){

        });
```